# parse_ini_file converts numeric values to string

Tags: php, string, parsing, numeric

I use the php command `parse_ini_file` to load the config of an application.
Looking at the php [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) there is example, wehere it looks like, that numeric values are excepted, by using those without quotes `"`.
So I used an init-file like that:

```
arr[] = 1
arr[] = 2
arr[] = "string"
integer_value = 3
```

Parsing that file with
`$init = parse_ini_file('myConfig.ini',0);`
i get the following result (`var_dump($init);`):

```
array(2) {
  ["arr"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "string"
  }
  ["integer_value"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

Is there a way to process integer values as integer, not as a string, to get the following result:

```
array(2) {
  ["arr"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    string(6) "string"
  }
  ["integer_value"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Blender PHP Version 5.3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation doesn't state anything about returning option values of corresponding type. In fact, they should be strings in common case. (But, if you want, you can check this [implementation](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#5969)). Instead you can apply simple callback, for example, via [`array_walk_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/array_walk_recursive):

```
$array = ["arr"=>["0", "1", "2"], "integer_value"=>"3", "float_value"=>"-0.5"];
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$value, $key)
{
    if(is_numeric($value))
    {
        $value = (string)((int)$value)===$value
            ?(int)$value
            :(double)$value;
    }
});
```

-check this [fiddle](http://3v4l.org/q7OOk).

Comment: Thank you: I like your script: it's simple and makes the job. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A bit old, but for whoever else comes here these days:

> As of PHP 5.6.1, *[the parameter $scanner_mode]* can also be specified as INI_SCANNER_TYPED. **In this mode boolean, null and integer types are preserved when possible.** String values "true", "on" and "yes" are converted to TRUE. "false", "off", "no" and "none" are considered FALSE. "null" is converted to NULL in typed mode. Also, all numeric strings are converted to integer type if it is possible.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php